# Simple CSV lexer

Tags: python, regex, csv, pygments

I want to color CSV files with pygments by column like here:

[image]

See that same column is colored with the same color.

Currently pygments doesn't include CSV parser because CSV is [said to be obscure format](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/642/add-csv-lexer). So I tried to write a minimal one myself. Here's what I tried:

```py
tokens = {
    'root': [
        (r'^[^,\n]+', Name.Function), # first column
        (',', Comment),               # separator
        (r'[^,\n]+', Name.Decorator), # second column
        (',', Comment),               # separator
        (r'[^,\n]+', Name.Constant),  # third column
        (',', Comment),               # separator
    ],
}
```

But it fails to color any column, but first:

[image]

As far as I know, pygments works by trying to match regexps one-by-one: when current regexp doesn't match -- it goes to the next one, and then all over again. If nothing matches it issues an error and advances one character (and puts that one in red box). For advanced cases like nested comments there are states, but I think for CSV one state might be sufficient.

Then I tried:

```py
tokens = {
    'root': [
        (',', Comment),                           # separator
        (r'^[^,\n]+', Name.Function),             # first column
        (r'(?:^[^,\n]+)[^,\n]+', Name.Decorator), # second column
    ],
}
```

But it colors all column as second one:

[image]

Here's a sample data:

```css
account_id,parent_account_id,name,status
,A001,English,active
A001,,Humanities,active
A003,A001,,active
A004,A002,Spanish,
```

In Emacs I managed to get what I wanted with:

```lisp
(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               "colors first 8 csv columns differently"
               (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,\n]*\\),"
                                              1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
               (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\)"
                                              2 'font-lock-variable-name-face)))
               (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\)"
                                              3 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
               (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\),\\([^,\n]*\\)"
                                              4 'font-lock-type-face)))
))
```

(I actually added more than 4 columns, but that is not important)

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: If fields can be empty, you should be using `[^,\n]*` instead of `[^,\n]+`.  That's what your Emacs version does.

Comment: @AlanMoore: it hangs if I do: with both variants.

Answer (score 8):

Oh I solved it using states:

```
tokens = {
    'root': [
        (r'^[^,\n]*', Name.Function, 'second'),
    ],
    'second': [
        (r'(,)([^,\n]*)', bygroups(Comment, Name.Decorator), 'third'),
    ],
    'third': [
        (r'(,)([^,\n]*)', bygroups(Comment, Name.Constant), 'fourth'),
    ],
    'fourth': [
        (r'(,)([^,\n]*)', bygroups(Comment, Name.Variable), 'fifth'),
    ],
    'fifth': [
        (r'(,)([^,\n]*)', bygroups(Comment, Keyword.Type), 'unsupported'),
    ],
    'unsupported': [
        (r'.+', Comment),
        ],
}
```

It colors first 5 CSV columns differently, and all the others as Comments:

[image]